# Why can't i do a contains here

Tags: c#, winforms

```
if (txt.Contains(textBox2.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) tabControl1.SelectedTab = tab;
```

I need it to be like a contains but i keep getting i can't do this
i get no overload mesage

full script

```
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TabPage tab in tabControl1.TabPages)
        {
            var controls = tab.Controls;
            foreach (Control c in controls)
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(Label))
                {
                    //depends if you want to search by label text or name 
                    string txt = c.Text;
                    //string name = c.Name;
                    //MessageBox.Show(txt);
                   // if (txt.Contains (textBox2.Text.Trim())) tabControl1.SelectedTab = tab;
                    if (txt.Contains(textBox2.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) tabControl1.SelectedTab = tab;
                    //MessageBox.Show(textBox2.Text.Trim());
                }
        }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: What makes you think you can't do that?

Comment: What type is txt? If it is textBox control you need: txt.Text.Contains....

Comment: edited scrip above

Comment: Add the full error message/stack trace.

Comment: how do i get the full error or stack trace over to you.

Comment: Just copy/paste it from the console or VS output window.

Comment: it says no overload for method 'contains ' takes 2 methods

Comment: @MatthewRodwell - when you include errors here, copy and paste them *exactly*. C# is case sensitive (Contains, not contains), and certainly the error actually says "...takes 2 **arguments**".

Comment: how is that helping me fix this issues

Comment: Because giving accurate info for a problem is extremely important to getting accurate help?

Comment: but if the person who is asking for help doesn't know as much as say you how can that person give more when they don't bloody know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the version of .NET you're using.

Notice .NET 4.8 only has one overload: [Contains(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8)

However, .NET Core 3.1 has [multiple overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-3.1), including the one you're using: [Contains (string, StringComparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Contains_System_String_System_StringComparison_)

There are ways around this, if you can't change frameworks. See this post for one example: [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Comment: Thank you solved from that link. setting to lower first works